# Angular 2 - Creating build for project

Tags: angular

I have used a quickstart heroes project to create a new project in Angular 2. I want to upload it on shared hosting server on which node js is not supported because of which I couldn't run it directly on the server. I tried using grunt & gulp but couldn't create build for the project i.e. all '.js' files into one single '.js' file(Concat). Need to know that what tool should I use to create a  build for the project? (Step by step guide would be really very helpful).

Comment: Did you try Angular CLI?

Comment: no....can you suggest me some tutorial from where I can use Angular CLI to create a build folder , so that all js files will be concatenated into 1 single js file ?